# VS2013 c++ connect mysql --- error in Libmysql.dll

Tags: c++, mysql, dll

main.cpp

```
#include "sqlConnection.h"
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    sqlConnection *sqlC = new sqlConnection();
    sqlC->ifSucceed();
}
```

sqlConnection.h

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <winsock.h>
#include "mysql.h"
#include <iostream>
#pragma once

using namespace std;

class sqlConnection
{
public:
    sqlConnection();
    ~sqlConnection();
    void ifSucceed();
    MYSQL mysql;
    MYSQL_RES *result;
    MYSQL_ROW row;
};
```

sqlConnection.cpp

```
#include "sqlConnection.h"

sqlConnection::sqlConnection()
{
    mysql_init(&mysql);
    mysql_real_connect(&mysql, "xxxxx", "xxxx", "xxxx", "librarySys", 7726, NULL, 0);   
}

void sqlConnection::ifSucceed() {
    char *sql = "select * from tb_bookcase";
    mysql_query(&mysql, sql);
    result = mysql_store_result(&mysql);
    if ((row = mysql_fetch_row(result)) != NULL) {
        cout << "succeed!" << endl;
    } else {
        cout << "faiiiiiiiiled" << endl;
    }
}

sqlConnection::~sqlConnection() {
}
```

> IF there is a libmysql.dll in source file error the message : There
>   are untreated exception:0x00007FFED00441E6 (libmysql.dll) (in the
>   librarySys.exe ) 0xC0000005:  Access conflict happened when reading 
>   0x0000000000000010.

And then I have to stop. VS give me choice, to change PDB, the binary file path and retry. But I do not know how to do it.

If I delete the libmysql.dll , the error message is:

> The program can not be started for losing libmysql.dll in the
>   computer.Try to reinstall this program to solve this problem.

It's so confusing! I have tried many ways to connect. There are always error messages.

Answer (score 1):

All `mysql_*` functions return a value that indicates success or failure. Your code disregards them. You ought to confirm whether calls were successful before proceeding to the next call. I surmise you actually failed to connect to the DB and your `MYSQL` is remains invalid.

Use your debugger. There's no point in coding in the dark. With your debugger you will quickly see whether your `MYSQL` object has been properly initialized.

Another thing:

```
sqlConnection *sqlC = new sqlConnection();
```

There is no reason for this to be heap allocated.